# Update Foreign Key and Primary Key Simultaneously using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following two table models :

```
class X_Table():
  L = Column(...)
  B = Column(...)
  Y_id = Column(String, ForeignKey(Y_Table.id, ON_UPDATE=CASCADE))

class Y_Table(X_Table):
  ..
  ..
  id = Column(String, ForeignKey(X_Table.id, ON_UPDATE=CASCADE))
```

Now I am trying to update the id in Y_Table. When doing that I get a foreign key violation . It's because Y_Table has a foreign key on X_Table. How do i update both together in SQLALchemy ?